# Rich Snippets - sitename in search (canonical website URL)

Tags: url, seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

Using the example from [Google structured data docs](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/site-name), I've added the Website Microdata to my site.

What bothers me is the description of the `url` prop:

> *url = the URL of your **official website** (required)*

Does *official website* mean the base URL of my website or the URL of the current requested page?

I know only that it is not a good practice to have same canonical URL on two different pages and the above description really confuse me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [`WebSite` type](http://schema.org/WebSite), the value of the [`url` property](http://schema.org/url) would be the URL that represents the whole website. This is typically the URL of the homepage.

(And for the [`WebPage` type](http://schema.org/WebPage), it would be the URL of that webpage.)

Comment: Will there be a problem with the canonical urls or I need to specify another canocical link tag that represents the current page from WebPage type?

Comment: Providing Schema.org has nothing to do with `rel`-`canonical`. If you have a `WebSite` type, you are saying something about a website (… it doesn’t even have to be your own website, and it doesn’t have to be part of the website you say something about). In case of Google’s Site Name snippet, you should probably not use a different URL in Schema.org’s `url` property vs. `rel`-`canonical` (so the URL for your Site Name snippet should typically be the canonical URL of your homepage).